# NetworkStream ReadTimeOut

Tags: c#, networking

I would like to understand how readtimeout works. In my case, my readtimeout is `20ms`. So, does it mean that readtimeout will always wait for 20ms eventhough I receive my data in 5ms?

```
ns.ReadTimeout = 20;
```

Comment: no, it will fail the read operation in case it was not enough time to complete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Accoring to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk6w7hs8(v=vs.110).aspx) it is the time in milliseconds after which the operation will throw an `IOException`.

> A Int32 that specifies the amount of time, in milliseconds, that will elapse before a read operation fails. The default value, Infinite, specifies that the read operation does not time out.
>
> If the read operation does not complete within the time specified by this property, the read operation throws an IOException.

If the operation completes before that, there will be no additional delay.